# Executing wix msi custom actions as system

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am using WIX to build a an MSI that will be executed as a regular user but with system privileges (AlwaysInstallElevated=1).  I have defined two Custom Actions that execute net.exe.
The net.exe commands are not getting executed as a regular user.  I have also tested executing this msi as an Administrator and the net.exe commands are getting executed.
I have logged the msi output and I see error codes that lead me to believe that the net.exe commands are not being executed elevated.  I'm reaching out to the community to see if

1. What I'm trying to do is possible
2. Do I need to instead use an exe as a custom action in order for the exe to install elevated.

Thanks in advance for the feedback.

```
<CustomAction Directory="TARGETDIR" ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]net.exe user TestUser /add" Return="ignore" Execute="deferred" HideTarget="no" Impersonate="no" Id="Command1">Command1</CustomAction>
<CustomAction Directory="TARGETDIR" ExeCommand="[SystemFolder]net.exe localgroup Administrators TestUser /add" Return="ignore" Execute="deferred" HideTarget="no" Impersonate="no" Id="Command2">Command2</CustomAction>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="Command1" After="PublishProduct">NOT Installed</Custom>
    <Custom Action="Command2" After="Command1">NOT Installed</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Machine Policy and User policy allows for msis to be executed as system.

```
MSI (c) (DC:F8) [09:17:39:438]: Machine policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 1
MSI (c) (DC:F8) [09:17:39:438]: User policy value 'AlwaysInstallElevated' is 1
MSI (c) (DC:F8) [09:17:39:438]: Running product '{34ED8E61-40EA-47CE-95E7-8EE3CDBCB1E8}' with elevated privileges: All apps run elevated.
```

Errors

```
MSI (s) (8C:8C) [20:39:18:989]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=Command1,,)
MSI (s) (8C:8C) [20:39:18:989]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=Command1,ActionType=3170,Source=C:\,Target=C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\net.exe user TestUser /add,)
CustomAction Command1 returned actual error code 2 but will be translated to success due to continue marking
MSI (s) (8C:8C) [20:39:19:535]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=Command2,,)
MSI (s) (8C:8C) [20:39:19:535]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=Command2,ActionType=3170,Source=C:\,Target=C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\net.exe localgroup Administrators TestUser /add,)
CustomAction Command2 returned actual error code 1 but will be translated to success due to continue marking
```

Answer (score 1):

Like **Phil** says, don't use **net.exe** to create users. Use WiX's built in features to do so (I should have found a better sample but don't have time right now):

- http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/user.html
- https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea/new-user-on-the-block/

My first instinct would be that the **AlwaysInstallElevated** policy would be misconfigured, but judging from the log file it is set correctly. I am rusty, but the **impersonation** looks like it is correctly set to "**no**" **Phil**? And the **scheduling** is **deferred** and seemingly placed right before InstallFinalize - seems OK off the top of my head.

Could it be that **net.exe** cannot be run properly as **LocalSystem**? Why then would it work when the installation is kicked off as Administrator? One would think LocalSystem had all required privileges. Isn't the current user's access token attached to the msiexec.exe process somehow? (for logging purposes or something). Or could it be a privilege that the Administrator account has that LocalSystem does not? How would that privilege apply if there is no impersonation? Did you try to manually launch net.exe as a regular user? What errors do you get when attempting to create a user when running as a regular user?

In either case I wouldn't waste my time running EXE custom actions if there is an alternative. I don't remember the last time I did. I normally use VBScript, C++ and earlier I used Installscript - with all its archaic syntax. **Just switch to the built-in WiX constructs and you should be fine.**

Answer (score 0):

Even in an install started by an administrator the impersonated custom actions run without elevation. So the answer is your number 2. start the install from an elevated process with a CreateProcess-type of initiation. Having said that, it's not clear to me why you can't run the CA deferred with no impersonation because there seems to be nothing that requires the user to be an actual user as opposed to the system account. So the failure might not be elevation, and that's the issue with passing the task off to a program that isn't going to give you good error messages. So....

I've seen boilerplate code to do this kind of thing, and I believe WiX has it anyway, the Util User element, that may be the way to go.

Comment: Phil, these results don't make sense to me. I think the CA is set deferred and impersonation is "no". There must be something else wrong. In either case he should switch to WiX's built-in features.

Comment: Stein, the post proposes (in point 2) to change the custom actions to run them impersonated and elevated because they are not working. My answer just says I see no reason why they don't work as specified, and therefore that the problem may not be simply an elevation requirement.  So I agree with you, because that's what I said, but maybe I'm missing the point of your comment somewhere.